# jQuery autocomplete doesn't see particular word

Tags: mysql, jquery-ui

If I run the following query in phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%story%'
```

I get the following result:
Showing rows 0 - 24 (37 total, Query took 0.0050 seconds.)

However, if I run the exact same query in 'search.php', using jQuery autocomplete:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#results" ).autocomplete({
source: 'search.php'
});
});
</script>
```

I get "No results found"

If I change the term to 'abba', for example,
in phpMyAdmin I get 24 results and in 'search.php' I get 24 results!

```
$db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);

//get search term and then remove all hyphens, spaces and apostrophes
$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
$searchTerm = str_replace('-', '', $searchTerm);
$searchTerm = str_replace(' ', '', $searchTerm);
$searchTerm = str_replace("'", "", $searchTerm);

$query = $db->query("SELECT myfield FROM mytable
    WHERE replace(replace(replace(myfield,'-',''),'\'',''),' ','')  LIKE '%$searchTerm%' 
    ");
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row['myfield'];
}
//return json data
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Please include the code being used within search.php. How is is the PHP outputting the data?

Comment: Remember: *... The Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results, instead a query string is added with a `term` field, which the server-side script should use for filtering the results... a GET request would be made to http://example.com?term=foo. The data itself can be in the same format as the local data described above.*

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Question edited to include php.

Comment: Where is `$searchTerm` defined? This doe snot seem complete.

Comment: This could also be susceptible to SQL Injection.